# Is "PlayOnLinux's virtual drives" folder necessary?

Tags: linux, wine, playonlinux

I am trying out *PlayOnLinux* and it created a symlink called "PlayOnLinux's virtual drives" in my `~` directory which I don't like. It is just a symlink to `~/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/` anyway, so is the symlink really necessary?

I'd rather just unlink it or even name it something more concise, but I don't want to screw anything up with the games or installations.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it;'s about general computing, not gaming.

Comment: @pppery I believe this is on-topic here since PlayOnLinux (and Wine) are software that is used mainly for gaming, like Steam. Wine and Steam-related questions are on-topic here and we even have a tag specifically for them with questions about their configuration (even though there's no video game involved). This also might be off-topic at the general computing SE, Super User, which doesn't allow video game-related questions.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, it’s just a symlink intended for the user to more easily find PlayOnLinux's wine prefix directories. You can savely rename or remove it, the software doesn’t rely on it.